# Clojure - How to check loop condition AFTER making calculation?

Tags: loops, clojure

I need to create a loop, that in a first step something should be calculated and result of that calculation should be passed to test condition. It's something like:

do (something) while (condition)

It's mandatory, that first pass should make calculation just before test condition should occur.

Is it possible to do in Clojure?

I've found similar problem here on StackOverflow, but it was unclear for me. Those solutions presented here are much more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, maybe:

```
(ns playground.core)

(defn do-while-loop [init-state do-something condition]
  (loop [state init-state]
    (let [next-state (do-something state)]
      (if (condition next-state)
        (recur next-state)
        next-state))))


playground.core> (do-while-loop 0 inc #(< % 6))
6
playground.core> (do-while-loop 0 inc #(< % 0))
1
```

init-state is the state you are looping on, do-something is a function to compute the next state, and condition is a function that returns a boolean value based on the state.

This is a purely functional do-while-loop with the condition being tested *after* the next state has been computed. And you can always add extra syntactic sugar on top of it using macros if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `loop` here. Whenever you can't decide how you want to loop, `loop` is a good starting point to feel things out since it's so general. A bare bones example would look like:

```
(loop []
  (let [result (some-calc)]
    (if (verify-result result) ; The condition
      (recur) ; Loop again
      result))) ; Or return the result of the calculation
```

Where `some-calc` is the producer, and `verify-result` checks if you should loop again.

You could even do away with the `loop` and use a recursive function:

```
(defn func []
  (let [result (some-calc)]
    (if (verify-result result)
      (recur)
      result)))
```

Comment: OK, that seems to be the solution for my idea, but what if I need to use calculations that have some "variables"? For instance: (/ (* 2 temp_val) some_number). Where I should put definitions of temp_val and some_number?

Comment: @Boba_Fett In the `let` inside the `loop`.

Comment: So it should look like this? `let [temp_val (blablabla)]` `let [some_number (blablabla)]` `let [result (/ (* 2 temp_val) some_number)`

Comment: @Boba_Fett You only need 1 `let`: `(let [temp-val (stuff) some-num (stuff) result (/ (* 2 temp-val) some-num)] result)`.

Comment: No, I'm just getting used to it :)

Comment: @Boba_Fett Oh, I see you've been using `def` instead of `let` when defining locally. Ya, definitely use `let` instead.

Comment: Yes, I will :) One more thing to clarify: `recur (something)` is operating inside of `let`?

Comment: @Boba_Fett Yes, because `result` is only available inside the let. All the vals defined by the let go out of scope when you leave it. If you want to recur with the result, it needs to be in the let.

Comment: OK, and what is the role of `loop` bindings? How do I affect them?

Comment: @Boba_Fett Using recur. This is getting a little broad, and hard to go over in comments. The Clojure docs on loop are very informative. If you look them over, it should make more sense.

Comment: @Boba_Fett https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop

Comment: @Boba_Fett Look at the third example, underneath the panda avatar.

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation. I'll follow Your guide.